# How to remove underline from image anchor

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

There is an invisible underline for my anchor and it's messing up the page. See below.

[image]

I have tried    `text-decoration:none;`

This code is inside `#header`

```
<?php 
if($cart_items > 0)
{
    ?>
    <div id="cart" >
    <?php echo anchor('shopping_basket/view_basket', '<img src="/e-com/images/cart.png" />'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="cartItms">
    <?php echo '('.$cart_items.')' ?>
    </div> <?php
}
```

CSS

```
#header {
height:100px;
width:1407px;
background-color:#294052;
}

#logo {
float:left;
}

#logo img {
margin-left:150px;
margin-top:6px;
}

#cart {
float:right;
}

#cart img {
margin-right:170px;
margin-top:28px;
}

#cartItms {
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
margin-top:30px;
}

#login {
float:right;
margin-right:60px;
margin-top:35px;
color:#fff;
}

#login a {
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Looks like an outline, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Comment: Hi ethio even it seems as design issue in your case but this is outline and is necessary for accessibility i.e. when user access your site by keyboard tab this outline is helpful for user understanding.

Comment: @Huangism The outline is created because I'm using the inspector tool in web developer. It is not visible without it, it becomes an unseen underline under the image.

Comment: @ethio then I am unsure of what you are asking because the outline in your image is the outline from your inspector. Are you talking about an underline when you hover an anchor tag?

Comment: Yes, there is an invisible underline that is part of the anchor and is pushing the other stuff on the page out of place.

Answer (score 1):

Add below CSS:

```
a {
    outline: 0;
}
```

For **IE9** just add : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

## Source : [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)

Comment: The outline is created because I'm using the inspector tool in web developer. It is not visible without it, it becomes an unseen underline under the image.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your text-decoration: none; ? you put in the right class for example:

```
#cart {
  float:right;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

or

img { text-decoration: none; }

also check in your browser doing some inspection, maybe there is something missing, like your class is not overriding your actual class or id, thats why you are still having this issue.